# Using HTTPS with a squid proxy

Tags: proxy, ssl, https, squid

I have a squid proxy set up on a few different servers. I am behind it on most applications (firefox, other apps that allow proxy config, etc). right now I'm not using https, and if I look in wireshark, the requests to and from my server and not encrypted(obviously). if i change squid to use ssl, will the data between my computer and my squid proxy be encrypted? i know that in order for data to be encrypted both ways the remote server (site im visiting) needs to be using ssl as well.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using this for browsing the Internet in general (rather then doing reverse proxying/accelleration for one site) ?  If so, how do you propose to redirect http -> https traffic ?

Answer (score 0):

my solution was to use an ssh tunnel to the server. shitty but it does what i need it to.